# dhtmlxGrid Smart Rendering doesn't send parameters

Tags: javascript, request, dhtmlx

i am trying to use dhhtmlxGrid with his smart rendering activated.
Here's my js code

```
function grid()
{
    var mygrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('products_grid');
    mygrid.setImagePath("codebase/imgs/");
    mygrid.setHeader("Product Name,Internal Code,Price");
    mygrid.setInitWidths("*,150,150");
    mygrid.setColAlign("left,left,right");
    mygrid.setSkin("modern");
    mygrid.init();
    mygrid.enableSmartRendering(true);
    mygrid.load("PrendiTutto", "json");
}
```

In my html i have a  tag that launch the application, and "PrendiTutto" is a servlet that is able to read from my database. My problem is that when the mygrid.load("PrendiTutto", "json") is launched there are no parameters passed to my servlet, while i know that the smartRendering uses the "count" and "posStart" parameters. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a damned file: dhtmlxgrid_json.js that is not mentioned in dhtmlx guides and samples. I have added it and now all is running well..